# Silent Installation for dotNetInstaller Bootstrapper

Tags: installation, silent, dotnetinstaller

I am using `dotNetInstaller` bootstrapper for adding pre-requisites like Postgresql 9.1
I want to silently install postgresql from the bootstapper.

I added the below command in the *executables section of the DotnetInstaller's Configuration file.

```
#APPPATH\prerequisits\postgresql-9.1.0-1-windows.exe /qn""
```

I am getting the error:

> Expected option but got "/qn". Options starts with leading -- ....

Please let me know what should be the silent installation option for postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late,just for the record. Did your bootstraper work ?

[Source](http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/pginst-guide)

Non-interactive installation

If you are a software author you may wish to embed the PostgreSQL installer within your own application installer. A non-interactive installer mode is provided to allow this in which only a progress bar will be shown to the user. Parameters may be passed to the installer either on the command line, or using an option file.

In order to start the installer in non-interactive mode, the --mode command line option is used (in conjunction with any other options that are required). For example, on Mac OS X:

$ sudo ./postgresql-8.4.0-b2-2-osx.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh --mode unattended [additional options]

Command line options

The following command line options are available to control the installation:

--prefix : Specifies the installation directory. Defaults to /opt/PostgreSQL/8.X on Linux, /Library/PostgreSQL/8.X on Mac OS X, and %PROGRAMFILES%\PostgreSQL\8.X on Windows.

--datadir : Specifies the data directory. Defaults to $PREFIX/data.

--superpassword : Specifies the superuser (and on Windows, service account) password to use. Defaults to postgres in non-interactive mode.

--port : Specifies the port number to listen on. Defaults to 5432.

--locale : Specifies the locale to initialise the cluster in. Defaults to the locale detected by initdb.

--create_shortcuts [1|0];: Specifies whether or not menu shortcuts should be created. Defaults to 1 (yes).

--install_plpgsql [1|0];: Specifies whether or not pl/pgsql will be installed in template1. Defaults to 1 (yes).

--install_runtimes [1|0]; (Windows only): Specifies whether or not install the Microsoft Visual C++ runtimes before the installation proceeds. Defaults to 1 (yes).

Option file

You can launch the installer using an option file, by passing the filename on the command line, for example:

## postgresql-8.4.0-1-linux.bin --optionfile /path/to/optionfile

The option file may contain the same parameters that are available on the command line, in a option=value format. For example:

prefix=/usr/local/pgsql84
datadir=/var/lib/pgsql84
port=5678